# How to access data attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm struggling with what is probably a very simple bit of jQuery

I have html like this:

```
<div class="star-rating" data-star-rating="5.0"></div>
<div class="star-rating" data-star-rating="2.0"></div>
```

I have some javascript which needs to do something based on the star rating of each of these elements and currently looks like this:

```
$('.star-rating').jRate({
    startColor : '#ccc',
    endColor : '#ccc',
    readOnly : true,
    rating : <value of data-star-rating>
});
```

I want to replace `<value of data-star-rating>` with the value of the data attribute relating to the element currently being processed

I thought this would work `$(this).data('starRating')` but it doesn't seem to

How can I access the value of the data attribute in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).data('star-rating')`?

Comment: what does `console.log((".star-rating").data('star-rating'))` return? You dont even loop through elements, which one should it get ? 5.0 or 2.0 ?

Comment: @ksno it returns whatever the 1st one is... not really relevant though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(this)` doesn't refer to the element on which the `jRate` function is being called.

You can use the selector if there is only a single element having that class

```
$('.star-rating').jRate({
    startColor : '#ccc',
    endColor : '#ccc',
    readOnly : true,
    rating : $('.star-rating').data('star-rating')
});
```

**For multiple elements:**

Iterate over all the elements having the class `star-rating` and attach the plugin `jRate` individually with the `rating` value of the respective element.

```
$('.star-rating').each(function () {
    $(this).jRate({
        startColor: '#ccc',
        endColor: '#ccc',
        readOnly: true,
        rating: $(this).data('star-rating')
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fenxca75/)<sup>Didn't find CDN link of that plugin, so added the minified code in JavaScript pane itself</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You can use this too :

```
$(this).data('star-rating');
```

**EDIT**

After reading again the question. Comments are right, you should iterate through `.star-rating` array to apply the jRate to each element, sorry for my misunderstanding.

```
$('.star-rating').each(function () {       
    $(this).jRate({
        startColor: '#ccc',
        endColor: '#ccc',
        readOnly: true,
        rating: $(this).data('star-rating')
    });
});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.

Comment: I don't know why this has 5 upvotes as this doesn't answer the question? Why `$(this).data('starRating');` has not worked as this is absolutely valid.

Comment: Just saying, after recent edit this looks exactly like [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36085321/2025923)

Answer (score 2):

As there are more than one elements having class "star-rating" so you will need to loop through the elemets and forEach loop will make current iterating element accessible into the loop so you can use that element. And apply the JRate.

```
 $('.star-rating').forEach(function(dateRating){
  $(dateRating).jRate({
  startColor : '#ccc',
  endColor : '#ccc',
  readOnly : true,
  rating :  $(dateRating).attr("data-star-rating")
 });
});
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: Added some description. I think this is so generic code anyone can understand If using JavaScript and JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You must use this:

```
$(this).attr('data-star-rating');
```

Comment: That's not true about `data()`. It will and does return HTML data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).data('star-rating')` will work if you return it from a function.

```
$('.star-rating').jRate({
    startColor : '#ccc',
    endColor : '#ccc',
    readOnly : true,
    rating : function () { return $(this).data('star-rating'); }
});
```